# How to mock methods called by method under the test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm working with legacy code and would like to increase the test coverage for it.

I have a class like:

```
public class MyStrategy implements SomeStrategy {

    TimeAndDateUtils timeAndDateUtils = new TimeAndDateUtils();

    @Override
    public boolean shouldBeExtracted(Argument argument) {
        Date currentDate = timeAndDateUtils.getCurrentDate();
        return currentDate.isBefore(argument.getDate());
    }

}
```

I would like to test the shouldBeExtracted-Method an mock the call to `timeAndDateUtils.getCurrentDate()` so that it returns some fixed value.

So what I'm trying to do is:

```
Date currentDate = %some fixed date%
TimeAndDateUtils timeAndDateUtils = Mockito.mock(TimeAndDateUtils.class);
Mockito.when(timeAndDateUtils.getCurrentDate()).thenReturn(currentDate);
Assert.assertTrue(myStrategy.shouldBeExtracted(argument))
```

How can I force the MyStrategy-Class to use the mocked object instead of creating it's own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mockito has a nice class for overriding private objects inside a class. It is called WhiteBox. It works like this

```
MyStrategy myStrategy = new MyStrategy();
TimeAndDateUtils timeAndDateUtils = Mockito.mock(TimeAndDateUtils.class);
Whitebox.setInternalState(myStartegy, "timeAndDateUtils", timeAndDateUtilsMock);
```

That will change your TimeAndDateUtils for your mock

Comment: While this would work, it's a bad solution. Instead, the method to be tested can easily be covered by two simple tests, passing an `Argument` containing a date before/after the current date. No mocking needed.

Comment: Doing it you are testing 2 pieces of legacy code at the same test. Unless TimeAndDateUtils is part of a known framework/library I wouldn't rely on the TimeAndDateUtils class and I would create tests for both classes not dependent to each other.

Comment: Well, a decade of experience (and thousands of tests created) taught me that integration tests are always better than isolated unit tests.

Comment: Both, TDD and BDD are usefull to ensure quality

Comment: Never used BDD, only TDD. (BDD requires that tests be created with the direct participation of non-technical stakeholders, which in practice is nearly impossible to get.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to put mock into MyStrategy object. It would look like this:

```
MyStrategy myStrategy = new MyStrategy(); // I don't know if you are using DI
MyStrategy.class.getDeclaredField("timeAndDateUtils").set(myStrategy, timeAndDateUtilsMock);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I found the solution of @kimi82 a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you cannot rewrite the existing code to make it more testable, this is the typical use case for the annotation [`@InjectMocks`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) allowing to **inject mock or spy fields** into tested object automatically.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyStrategyTest {
    @Mock
    private TimeAndDateUtils timeAndDateUtils;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyStrategy myStrategy;

    @Test
    public void testShouldBeExtracted() {
        ...
        Mockito.when(timeAndDateUtils.getCurrentDate()).thenReturn(currentDate);
        Assert.assertTrue(myStrategy.shouldBeExtracted(argument));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an old Java SE application without any DI

Comment: Hello @Nicolas, 

I'm using Mockito 1.9.x. I use InjectMocks extensively in other projects. I have also tried it in this one, even before asking on stack overflow. For some reasons it didn't work, so I thought, it would have something to do with absolutely lack of DI in this project. 

But due to your explanations, it should actually have worked. I'll give it another try. 

Thx, Iryna.

Comment: I have just tested the exact same code with Mockito `1.9.5` and it works perfectly

Comment: make sure to annotate your Test class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Comment: Hello @Nicolas after annotating myStrategy with @InjectMocks I cannot mock the method call anymore. I get then an error message: `when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.`

Comment: I don't know how you test exactly, what I know is that it works on my side with what you provided

Answer (score 0):

`timeAndDateUtils` is being created in the class itself which make it difficult to access for test. inject the dependency via constructor so that a mock can be created

```
public class MyStrategy implements SomeStrategy {

    TimeAndDateUtils timeAndDateUtils;

    public MyStrategy(TimeAndDateUtils timeAndDateUtils) {
        this.timeAndDateUtils = timeAndDateUtils;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldBeExtracted(Argument argument) {
        Date currentDate = timeAndDateUtils.getCurrentDate();
        return currentDate.isBefore(argument.getDate());
    }

}
```

Test

```
//Arrange
Date currentDate = %some fixed date%
TimeAndDateUtils timeAndDateUtils = Mockito.mock(TimeAndDateUtils.class);
Mockito.when(timeAndDateUtils.getCurrentDate()).thenReturn(currentDate);

MyStrategy myStrategy = new MyStrategy(timeAndDateUtils);

//Act 
bool result = myStrategy.shouldBeExtracted(argument);

//Assert
Assert.assertTrue(result);
```

Comment: The class is one of implementations of a common interface "SomeStrategy". I don't like changing the constructor only for one of them. It makes the code even less readable as it already is.